# How can I increase the frequency that a lambda pull dynamodb stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My lambda is triggered by a dynamodb table stream. Based on the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html, `Lambda polls shards in your DynamoDB stream for records at a base rate of 4 times per second. When records are available, Lambda invokes your function and waits for the result. If processing succeeds, Lambda resumes polling until it receives more records.`

This means I will get about 250 millionseconds latency to trigger my lambda when there is an update happens on dynamodb. Is there a way to improve this pull rate?

Comment: I don't think you have any control on the aws "pullers" except batch size and the other common options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the polling interval, you can only change things like the `batch size` or the `parallelization factor`.

Here you can look up the possibilities of configuration, when invoking a lambda through DynamoDBStreams:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-dynamodb.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that these configuration `batch size ` or `parallelization factor` only reduce the times of pull every second.